# How MiYodea and other knowledge-sharing sites influence the future of Judaism?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory, internet

The previously unknown availability and abundance of knowledge, both religious, and scientific surely impose a serious challenge to the existing structure of Torah study. I hear many Rabbis, Ram"im, Mashgichim complaining about losing their authority in the eyes of the new generation of Bachurim that have access to the Internet and Jewish knowledge-sharing sites such as [Forum Otzar](http://forum.otzar.org/), or MiYodea or even Quora.

How do contemporary Rabbis see the long-lasting influence of those sites on the future of Judaism and the Jewish Orthodox community?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96287/discussion-on-question-by-al-berko-how-miyodea-and-other-knowledge-sharing-sites).